# I have to send the javascript object to jsp with the help of ajax and then convert jsp objects to java objects and print it to xmlhttpresponse?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

index.jsp

```
<html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>JSP Page</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">    
      function sendData()
      {
         var data={"id":101,"name":"suraj"};              
         var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();    
         var url="File1.jsp";

         url = url + "?data="+data;    
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);            
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {  
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
       }
      </script>
   </head>
<body>
 <h3> To send data through json : </h3>
 <input type="button" value="sendData" onClick="sendData()"/>
  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

// the javascript object has to be sended to jsp page with the help of ajax , and i have to convert that javascript object to java objects , how can i perform that task

```
File1.jsp

<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONValue"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser"%>    
<%     
  String data=request.getParameter("data");    
  out.println("<h3>data sended successfully <h3>"+data);       
   String jsonn=JSONValue.toJSONString(data);      
  out.println(jsonn);    
  JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();      
  JSONObject json=(JSONObject)parser.parse(jsonn);      
  String name=(String)json.get("name");      
  int id=(int)json.get("id");      
  out.println(id+"   "+name);     
  %>
```

here i tried to parse it to json object and then convert it to java object, which is not happening ...
  // I cant convert that javascript object to java variables . Help me out with the piece of code . what should i do to convert the javascript object to java objects

Comment: You're question doesn't appear to be specific enough. Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In general, good questions will include error messages encountered while attempting to solve the problem. "i tried ... which is not happening" is not very helpful.

Comment: If you are using only two variables send it like `url = url + "?id="+id+"?name="+name;` as two parameters.

Comment: Sir, but i was trying  to send the json variable from one jsp to another jsp ................. so please help me out for that

Comment: what are the steps we have to take while dealing with json objects?
If i am passing javascript object from one html file to jsp file , what are the steps i have to take , so that to convert that json object to java object ? And also what are the steps i should take to pass the json object from one jsp file to the html page.